FD-SOI Channel formation with fully depleted body
In an FD-SOI the body is undoped, which could be just an intrinsic semiconductor such as silicon. What I'm wondering is how the channel is formed in an FD-SOI when the body isn't doped at all. My guess is when a positive voltage is applied to the gate, the valence electrons from the Silicon atoms are excited and then attracted to the top, creating the channel. And so the channel formation process is mostly by electrostatic induction and without replying on dopants, isn't it?
If it is the case, then could a traditional bulk CMOS device with an undoped body create the channel in a similar manner, without the need for dopants?
